# Handle data present only in training set for Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction

So i have a classification problem, in which i have to classify crimes into categories based on different features ( SF Crime competition on Kaggle for those who are familiar). An interesting aspect which takes place in this data set is that there are 2 extra features "Descript"and "Resolution",both containing short text, which are present ONLY in the training set and not in the test set. They both have little pieces of text as values such as "UNDER INFLUENCE OF ALCOHOL IN A PUBLIC PLACE","VIOLATION OF STAY AWAY ORDER",etc.

My question is, how can I use these fields even though they appear only in the training set ? Currently I am discarding them, but I want to extract some info from them.

Comment: Can you split the training set into three separated sets for training, validation and test?

Comment: yes i could, but to what purporse? What should i do when it comes the time to try and classify on the real test test which doesn't have those features ?

Comment: If the real data don't have those features, there is no sense in using the features during training. In my opinion the classification model can consist only of the features, which present in the real data.